# Табличный вывод связанных данных

Tags: yii

Есть 4 таблицы:
results(результаты): ResID | ResCodeConc | ResName | ResDate
marks(баллы): MarkID | MarkCodeResult | MarkExp
conclusions(заключение): ConcID | ConcName
conc_fields(поля): FieldID | FieldCodeNameConc | FieldName

Один результат имеет множество баллов, отношение один ко многим.
Результат имеет тип (ResCodeConс) из таблицы conclusions, отношение один к одному.
В свою очередь заключение (conclusions) имеет множество полей, отношение один ко многим.

Сделал так, в модели Results:

```
'marks' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Marks', 'MarkCodeResult'),  
'conclusions' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Conclusions',array('ResCodeConc '=>'ConcID ')),
'conc_fields' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ConcFields', array('ConcID '=>'FieldCodeNameConc'),'through'=>'conclusions')
```

По отдельности все работает, т.е.:
отдельно поля заключения:

```
foreach($results->conc_fields as $field) echo $field->FieldName;
```

отдельно баллы:

```
foreach($results->marks as $mark) echo $mark->MarkExp;
```

Но не получается сделать вот так, название поля - балл
FieldName | MarkExp

Comment: Итоговый запрос в базу как выглядит?

Comment: Не понял какой запрос? Запрос который уже по отношениям формируется?

Запросы по отдельности:
SELECT f.FieldName
FROM `conc_fields` f 
INNER JOIN `conclusions` n ON f.FieldCodeNameConc = n.ConcID 

SELECT m.MarkExp
FROM `marks` m 
INNER JOIN `results` r ON m.MarkCodeResult = r.ResID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам запрос должен быть таким.

```
SELECT conc_fields.FieldName, marks.MarkExp 
FROM conc_fields, results, marks 
WHERE (results.ResCodeConc=conc_fields.FieldCodeNameConc) and (results.ResID=marks.MarkCodeResult)
```

в общем-то на вскидку вот так должно прокатить

```
$results=Results::model()->with(array('marks','conc_fields'))->findAll();
foreach($results as $rows){
  print $rows->marks->MarkExp;
  print $rows->conc_fields->FieldName;
}
```

без схемы мне было трудно понять
[image]